# Finding occurences of a digit in a number by recursion in Matlab

Tags: matlab

This recursive function takes two input arguments,  The first (A) is a number and the second (n) is a digit, checks the occurrence of n in A. (A is updated by removing its last digit in each recursion). it seems like the recursion is infinite and the base case (A == 0) is not valid but why.

```
function counts = countn(A,n)
    if (A == 0)
        counts= 0;
    end
    if (n == mod(A,10))
        disp(A);
        disp(floor(A/10));
        disp(mod(A,10));
        B = floor(A/10);
        counts = countn(B,n) + 1;

    else 
       B = floor(A/10);
       countn(B,n);
    end 
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not stop because it first evaluates the first if statement `if( A == 0)` and afterward the `if (n == mod(A,10))` where it jumps in the else branch and recursively calls the function again. So it does not stop in the first `if` statement as you likely expected it to do.

something like this should work:

```
function counts = countn(A,n)
    if (A == 0)
        counts = 0;
    elseif (n == mod(A,10))
            disp(A);
            disp(floor(A/10));
            disp(mod(A,10));
            B = floor(A/10);
            counts = countn(B,n) + 1;
    else 
       B = floor(A/10);
       counts = countn(B,n);
    end 
end
```

You also have to update count `counts` variable in the `else` branch to avoid the uninitialized use of variables.

Have a look at how to use a debugger [manual](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html). Simply click on the line number inside your function and run your code. Use the F10 and F11 keys to evaluate your code line by line. This helps you understand what your program does.